# How do I "Close Connection" like TCPView does, using the command line?

Tags: tcp

I'd like to do what TCPView does from the command line, for example, closing a connection used by a particular process (without ending the process). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I really don't understand why this question is closed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html - see "Closing a connection from Command-line" section (I've not tried it).

Answer (score 2):

You could use hping3 to send a tcp reset from the same source port to the same destination ip/port as the connection you'd like to close.  `netstat -b` will give you the process information.

Comment: Seems a bit heavyweight as it requires installing winpcap (driver + DLLs) as a dependency. Not sure what that would do to my system.

Answer (score 1):

[Tcpkill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpkill) from [dsniff](http://monkey.org/~dugsong/dsniff/) performs a bruteforce on the tcp sequence to send RST to the target flow. Use it with `lsof` or `netstat` to get the open sockets, then kill them :

```
petrus@seth:~$ sudo lsof -i TCP:80
COMMAND    PID   USER TYPE NODE NAME
chromium- 2674 petrus IPv4 TCP  seth:44545->stackoverflow.com:www  (ESTABLISHED)

petrus@seth:~$ sudo tcpkill -9 port 44545
tcpkill: listening on eth0 [port 44545]
64.34.119.12:80 > 172.22.151.34:44545: R 2186116153:2186116153(0) win 0
64.34.119.12:80 > 172.22.151.34:44545: R 2186116230:2186116230(0) win 0
64.34.119.12:80 > 172.22.151.34:44545: R 2186116384:2186116384(0) win 0
64.34.119.12:80 > 172.22.151.34:44545: R 2186116615:2186116615(0) win 0
```

Comment: Hmm, just saw that you installed winpcap... So I guess dsniff won't help you :(

Answer (score -2):

You can try wkillcx.

wkillcx can close an active connection.

You can download wkillcx at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/wkillcx/

It's freeware.

You can also view an example at the end of this post (it's in Spanish):

http://www.sysadmit.com/2015/01/windows-eliminar-conexiones-activas-tcp.html